# How can I "copy as curl" in Safari?

Tags: safari

Is it possible to do "copy as curl" like in Google Chrome and Firefix in Safari? I didn't find anything on google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** Safari 10 seems to support copy as curl. Just right click on `domain` column and select `copy as curl`.

I spent quite time trying to debug my webapps in Safari, instead of Chrome, But it seems to be impossible at least for my requirements (ReactDevTools and ReduxDevTools for example.). So I eventually gave up and now I'm using Chrome to debug and Safari to surf. About this particular question I'm pretty sure that there's no way to "copy as curl" a request in Safari.

Answer (score 2):

I know this super old but it is possible to copy cURL requests in safari:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) to intercept your requests. This has a 'Copy as cUrl' action in the context menu just like Chrome.

Comment: Great, I was able to run ReactDevTools in Safari too (in electron actually).

Comment: Wish someday we can have these features in Safari itself instead of running apps in parallel.

Comment: Ah, cool. Yeah, I don't get why such basic features aren't in there either.